# Install Laravel framework in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, server, lamp, laravel

I am using ubuntu 14.04. I have made setup LAMP. I came to know about [Laravel](http://laravel.com) framework. So I want to install it in my system. So can someone tell me how to install Laravel on my system? Any help and suggestions will be really appreciable.

Answer (score 1):

First install [Composer](https://getcomposer.org/) "The Dependency Manager for PHP" by this command:

```
    curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
    mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer
```

or read [Composer installation](https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md)

Then install Laravel project by this command:

```
    composer create-project laravel/laravel your-project-name --prefer-dist
```

or read [Laravel Quickstart](http://laravel.com/docs/quick)

that's it.

Now run your project by:

```
    php artisan serve
```

enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

Follow below steps for laravel installation:

**Install composer**

```
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
  
sudo mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer
  
sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/composer
```

After installation, on typing `composer` in terminal you'll get
[image: composer]

**Laravel Basic Requirements:**

If you are not using Homestead, you will need to make sure your server meets the following requirements:

- PHP >= 7.3
- BCMath PHP Extension
- Ctype PHP Extension
- Fileinfo PHP Extension
- JSON PHP Extension
- Mbstring PHP Extension
- OpenSSL PHP Extension
- PDO PHP Extension
- Tokenizer PHP Extension
- XML PHP Extension
- PHP >= 7.2.0
- JSON PHP Extension
- Mbstring PHP Extension
- OpenSSL PHP Extension
- PDO PHP Extension

**Install Laravel**

```
composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel project-name
```

After laravel gets installed, assign permission to your `storage, bootstrap` folder as like bellow:

```
sudo chmod  -R 777 storage  

sudo chmod  -R 777 bootstrap
```

Now your project is ready to run, using serve command:

```
 php artisan serve
```

Check detailed documentation check [laravel-installation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/installation)